# Import MXNet file in Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, mxnet

I am having trouble finding the answer to this.

I have an MXNet file in the form of:
`model.json` and `model.params.` What is the cleanest way to load the network into a Keras installation with TensorFlow backend?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot load native MXNet models into  Keras.

You can try to convert your model using [MMdnn](https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn), but depending on complexity of your model it might not work.